# Getting all values from BlockBlob Metadata starting with specific key string

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I have a `BlockBlob` image with multiple metadata attributes. Some metadata attributes are unique. Others start with a key identifier (in this case "Tag").

How would I get all the values for metadata properties starting with a specific string?

Here's an example of a `BlockBlob` image:

[image: BlockBlob Image with Tag Metadata]

There are multiple "Tag" elements starting with an index of 0.

Here's the *manual* way of doing this, but you would need to know each and every index that exists:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = await GetCloudBlobClientAsync();
CloudBlobDirectory directory = container.GetDirectoryReference(path);

// Get max of 100 blobs including their metadata properties
var blobs = await directory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(false, BlobListingDetails.Metadata, 100, null, null, null);
foreach (var blob in blobs.Results) {
    var imageBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(blob.Uri);
    var blockBlob = imageBlob.GetBlockBlobReference(imageBlob.Name);
    await blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync();

    // This is what I'm trying to do..
    var tagArray = [ blockBlob.Metadata["Tag0"], blockBlob.Metadata["Tag1"], ... ]
    // Returns ["outdoor", "nature", "man" ...]

    // Bonus if it included the key names as well..
    var tagArrayWithKeys = [ "Tag0": blockBlob.Metadata["Tag0"], ... ];
    // Returns [ "Tag0": "outdoor", "Tag1": "nature", "Tag2": "man", ...]
}
```

How would you do this dynamically?

Comment: CloudBlockBlob.Metadata is an object of type `IDictionary<string, string>`. Can't you simply enumerate over this and extract key and value from each entry?

Comment: @gauravmantri that'd be one way of approaching it if there weren't more unique identifiers than just "content". I am looking to enumerate through and a `FromPattern` or `StartsWith` or `Contains`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gaurav said, if you want to get one blob's all metadata,  you can do a loop to get them. For example

```
CloudBlobContainer container = await GetCloudBlobClientAsync();
CloudBlobDirectory directory = container.GetDirectoryReference(path);



// Get max of 100 blobs including their metadata properties
var blobs = await directory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(false, BlobListingDetails.Metadata, 100, null, null, null);
foreach (var blob in blobs.Results) {
    var imageBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(blob.Uri);
    var blockBlob = imageBlob.GetBlockBlobReference(imageBlob.Name);
    await blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync();
    foreach(var r in blockBlob.Metadata){
     Console.WriteLine("Key: " + r.Key + " value: " + r.Value);

}

}
```

Besides, if you want to get the metadata filter by the keys, please refer to the following code

```
CloudBlobContainer container = await GetCloudBlobClientAsync();
CloudBlobDirectory directory = container.GetDirectoryReference(path);



// Get max of 100 blobs including their metadata properties
var blobs = await directory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(false, BlobListingDetails.Metadata, 100, null, null, null);
foreach (var blob in blobs.Results) {
    var imageBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(blob.Uri);
    var blockBlob = imageBlob.GetBlockBlobReference(imageBlob.Name);
    await blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync();
    var result = blockBlob.Metadata.where(k => k.Key.StartsWith("Tag"))
    foreach(var r in result){
     Console.WriteLine("Key: " + r.Key + " value: " + r.Value);

}
}
```